# Riemann-Roch to find the distance and the rate of Goppa code

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the curve $x^5+y^5+z^5=0$ over $F_4$. Let $P_0, ..., P_{64}$ be the $F_{16}$-rational points of $W$ and $G:= aP_0$ with a < 64 and $D:= \sum_{i=1}^{64} P_i$ .

What can be a "good" bound on the distance and the rate of the algebraic geometric Goppa code $C(D, G)$?

I thought it would be a good idea to use Riemann-Roch, but I'm not sure if it really is... Could anyone confirm this or tell me how to do it in a better way? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: In response to your mention of Riemann-Roch, it is the Riemann-Roch theorem that tells you about the dimension $k$ of the code. This can be found in the section of Stichtenoth's book mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading chapter 2 of "Stichtenoth's Algebraic Function Fields and Codes", in particular Theorem 2.2.2 and the following corollary.

The standard bound for AG-codes gives $d \geq 64 - a$ in your situation. This bound is obtained as follows:

If $f \in L(G)$ evaluates on the points of $D$ to give a codeword of weight $d$, then exactly $64-d$ of $P_1,\ldots,P_{64}$ are zeros of $f$. Then

$$64-d \leq \deg \operatorname{div}_0(f) =  \deg \operatorname{div}_\infty(f) \leq \deg G = a.$$

Of course this general bound may not be sharp. After a brief internet search, it looks like the following papers contain some improvements:

- Stichtenoth, "A Note on Hermitian Codes"
- Yang and Kumar, "On the True Minimum Distance of Hermitian Codes"